# How do I create a new table taking columns from information_schema.columns with scale and precision?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a table from information_schema.columns. I need precision and scale so that it helps me with decimal datatype. The problem I face here is for INT I get precision and scale, which cannot be inserted. Can someone help me with selecting the columns? 
Eg:
I need select statement which gives such a output
I'm selecting from table A, it has 3 columns

```
name varchar(10),
price decimal(5,2),
Id int,
```

What I get from the query I framed

```
name varchar(10),
price decimal(5,2),
Id int(10,0)
```

current query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME +' ' + DATA_TYPE + ISNULL('('+CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10))+') ','') + ISNULL('('+CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR),'')+ISNULL(','+CAST(NUMERIC_SCALE)AS VARCHAR)+')','')+',' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: Please show your current attempt

Comment: @Zaynul can you please give me a solution

Comment: @user9208802 - can you show your current attempt / query?

Comment: There are no short-cuts here, you'll have to hardcode that part. (Luckily there aren't so many data types.)

Comment: My Current attempt : SELECT COLUMN_NAME +' ' + DATA_TYPE + ISNULL('('+CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10))+') ','') + ISNULL('('+CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR),'')+ISNULL(','+CAST(NUMERIC_SCALE)AS VARCHAR)+')','')+',' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='A'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME +' ' + DATA_TYPE + 

case DATA_TYPE when 'VARCHAR'  then

ISNULL('('+CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10))+') ','')
+ ISNULL('('+CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR),'')
+ ISNULL(','+CAST(NUMERIC_SCALE AS VARCHAR)+')','')+','

 when 'nVARCHAR'  then

ISNULL('('+CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10))+') ','')
+ ISNULL('('+CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR),'')
+ ISNULL(','+CAST(NUMERIC_SCALE AS VARCHAR)+')','')+','

when 'decimal'  then

ISNULL('('+CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10))+') ','')
+ ISNULL('('+CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR),'')
+ ISNULL(','+CAST(NUMERIC_SCALE AS VARCHAR)+')','')+','

else
''
end 

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='A'
```

but you should add your case if you have more then what I did

Answer (score 0):

try this if it works

```
create table Tbl
(
    name varchar(10),
    price decimal(5,2),
    Id int
)

select 
concat(
    name,' ',
    case system_type_id 
        when 167 then 'varchar('+cast(max_length as varchar(10))+'), ' 
        when 106 then 'decimal('+cast(precision as varchar(10))+','+cast(scale as varchar(10))+'), '
        when 56 then 'int, ' 
        --add more case for more datatype
    else '' end
    )
From sys.columns 
where object_id=(select object_id from sys.tables where name='tbl')
```